# Float buttons on both the left and right sides of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have buttons of varying length in a `div` of fixed dimensions:

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>No, Click Me</button>
  <button>No, me</button>
  <button>No, me</button>
  <button>No, me</button>
  <button>No, me</button>
  <button>No, me</button>
  <button>Alright, you can click them</button>
  <button>What about me?</button>
  <button>I don't care</button>
  <button>Click Whoever</button>
  <button>OMG I'm a button</button>
  <button>Filler Button</button>
  <button>Filler Button</button>
  <button>Filler Button</button>
  <button>Filler Button</button>
  <button>Filler Button</button>
</div>
```

By default the buttons are all lined up on the left, and of course if you `float:right` then they will align on the right.

I am wondering how it is possible to have the leftmost button in each row align to the left and the rightmost to align on the right, while splitting up that extra space evenly between the buttons in that row.

Is there any easy way of achieving something like this?

Here's a codepen: [Click me](http://codepen.io/cavanflynn/pen/RryeJo)

Comment: Just use <button style="float:right">Click Me</button> for floating right and left for left.

Comment: http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/WrJaLy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the [flex box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) we can achieve what you want:

```css
div {
  background: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button>Click Me</button>
  <button>No, Click Me</button>
  <button>No, me</button>
  <button>No, me</button>
  <button>No, me</button>
  <button>No, me</button>
  <button>No, me</button>
  <button>Alright, you can click them</button>
  <button>What about me?</button>
  <button>I don't care</button>
  <button>Click Whoever</button>
  <button>OMG I'm a button</button>
  <button>Filler Button</button>
  <button>Filler Button</button>
  <button>Filler Button</button>
  <button>Filler Button</button>
  <button>Filler Button</button>
</div>
```

Bear in mind there will be [some compatibility issues](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) without the required [prefixes](http://shouldiprefix.com/#flexbox).

Comment: Exactly what i was trying to achieve. Completely forgot about flexbox

Comment: @cfly24 Glad to hear it! Yeah there's a lot of features in flex-box that not many people know about so it's worth looking into for the future :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, like this: http://codepen.io/dirtysmith/pen/pgVxGQ

just add this to your css:

```
div > button:nth-child(even){float: right; clear: both;}
div > button:nth-child(odd){float: left;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decide you are willing to manually separate them into their perspective rows you can use flexbox. Use the `justify-content` property and set it to `space-between`

```css
div#parent {
  background: blue;
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
}
div#parent div.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div id='parent'>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>Click Me</button>
    <button>No, Click Me</button>
    <button>No, me</button>
    <button>No, me</button>
    <button>No, me</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>No, me</button>
    <button>No, me</button>
    <button>Alright, you can click them</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>What about me?</button>
    <button>I don't care</button>
    <button>Click Whoever</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>OMG I'm a button</button>
    <button>Filler Button</button>
    <button>Filler Button</button>
    <button>Filler Button</button>
  </div>
  <div class='row'>
    <button>Filler Button</button>
    <button>Filler Button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/dustinpoissant/pen/WrJaPy)

It's a little more work to group them into rows but that is the only thing I can think of.

Reference: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/